# Connection timed out when ssh to remote server IP

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, remote-desktop

I need to connect to a remote server and the data they give me to do so is:

A web server name, a public IP, a private IP and a myUserName.pem cert.

To connect to the server I do:

```
ssh -v myUserName@publicIP
```

Also:

```
ssh -v -i /home/myUserName/.ssh/myUserName.pem myUserName@publicIP
```

but I always get a time-out error.

I check the vpn:

```
nmcli c show --active | grep vpn
```

I check the port 22:

```
 sudo lsof -i:22
```

The state of ssh:

```
sudo service ssh status
```

All this works well.

I try a different port adding `-p 443` to the ssh lines but I keep getting the error.

So I try the IPs with:

```
traceroute -e
```

and with the two IPs I get asterisks/stars at the end.

I check:

```
sudo ufw status
```

And shows inactive.

The rest of the people who try to access this server do it without any problem, so I understand that it is a problem in the code I use or in my Internet connection configuration. But I don't know how I should keep checking things out to be able to connect to this server. Any idea can help me a lot.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds like the firewall doesn't allow you to get in - check that you are able to connect via `nc <host> 22`. If not, fix your firewall / VPN connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure on this one, but here are some ideas:

Connectivity should be OK, else you would get a "no route to host"
ssh -v (known bad ip address)

Validate the SSH protocol version you're running vs the remote system
ssh -v localhost    then ssh -v (remote system)

If your sure the protocol is OK, next check the keys.  Move the keys to a new location and see if it prompts you for a key.

Comment: I am so desperate that any idea is welcome, it can be a clue to help the solution so thank you very much!!
SSH protocol version is the same and although I change the keys there's no prompt for them. It times out before anything.